# Unicode and wxPython TextCtrl

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, encoding, wxpython

I am looking to display a .pdf file in wxPython, exactly as it would appear if one were to open said .pdf file with Windows Notepad. Everything in my program works, except when my data is sent to the txtctrl. The relevant portion of my code is:

```
def DoOpen(self):
    """Show file open dialog and open file"""
    wildcard = "pdf Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self,message="Open a File",wildcard=wildcard,style=wx.FD_OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        with codecs.open(path, 'rb','utf8','ignore') as handle:
            text = handle.read()
            print (text)
            self.txtctrl.SetValue(text)
            self.file = path
    dlg.Destroy()
```

The print statement prints to my interpreter as it should appear in my program. But after the data is passed through the SetValue method, the text outputted to wxPython terminates as soon as it hits my first object stream, exactly as it would appear if I omitted 'ignore' when opening the file to read.

I have read http://wiki.wxpython.org/UnicodeBuild and have become even more confused in the process. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a recent wxPython version? It seems all builds are unicode builds nowadays. However, the download page mentions *although string objects passed to wx APIs will still be converted automatically if possible*, which leaves me wondering.

Comment: Wx version 3.0.1.1 msw (classic)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `wx.TextCtrl` only supports *valid* UTF-8 input. Since the "characters" in a PDF object stream are not UTF-8, you could transform it before passing it to the `wx.TextCtrl`. You could try decoding using the `raw_unicode_escape` codec instead of `utf-8`, for example.